# Yii advanced search not working with specific search function based on the relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord

In my system, I have 3 types of user, ***Admin***, ***Supervisor*** and ***Normal user***. Every type of user has a ***Supervisor*** who is another user itself.
 
Suppose we have two tables, `users` and `documents` and the relation is as follow:[image]

Here the `documents` table is related with `users` table by `user_id` column.
In my system, I have a CGridview of `Documents` module based on the logged in user type. If the logged in user type is ***Admin***, then it shows all the entry of the `document` table.
If the logged in user type is ***Supervisor***, then it will show only those entry from `documents` table, where the `documents.user_id` is equal to those `users.user_id`, whose `users.sp_id = LoggedInUser`, sorry if I can't express it clearly.

I can show the data in CGridview by using relation in the `Documents` model.

```
public function relations(){
 'users' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
}
```

and in the  `Document` model I declare two custom functions to return the desired  DataProvider. Those are:

`public function searchByUser($id)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->condition = "user_id=$id";
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'doc_id DESC',
            ),
        ));
    }`

and

```
public function searchBySupervisor($supervisor_id)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->with=array('users'); 
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id,true);      
        $criteria->condition = "sp_id=$supervisor_id AND status='active'";
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'doc_idDESC',
            ),
        ));
    }
```

In my `/documents/admin`view, I use the **dataProvider**  based on the loggedin user in the CGridview:

```
if ($UserType=="Normal_User"){
        $this->widget(
        'booster.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->searchByUser(Yii::app()->user->getId()),


elseif($UserType == "supervisor"){

        $this->widget(
            'booster.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->searchBySupervisor(Yii::app()->user->getId()),
```

Everything is working fine except my search function isn't working. If I logged in as the supervisor, means if I use this: `'dataProvider'=>$model->searchBySupervisor(Yii::app()->user->getId()),` dataprovider, my advance search option doesn't filter the gridview based on the searching parameter, its returning same data.